# Rails ActiveStorage detach/attach solution working in development environment, but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm new to Rails and was hoping to ask for some guidance here. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

I have a feature that allows files that have been uploaded to a blog post to be re-ordered. My solution works in the development environment where files are uploaded to local storage. When files are re-ordered and saved, the re-order persists. In production (files are stored in Amazon S3), the re-order does not persist after save.

The file info is saved in the 'active_storage_blobs' table and their relationship to the blog post is saved in the 'active_storage_attachments' table.

In my current solution, when the files are re-ordered, I detach any file attachments to the post, and then create new attachments to the post (see below).

```
        @post.files.detach if files_params
        files_params.pluck('signed_id').each { |i| @post.files.attach(i) } if files_params
```

This results in the old attachments being deleted from active_storage_attachments (see id 239, 240 in the first snippet below) and new attachments being made (see id 241, 242 in the second snippet).

```
connect_development=# SELECT * FROM active_storage_attachments; 
 id  |  name  | record_type | record_id | blob_id |         created_at         
-----+--------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------------------------
  10 | avatar | User        |        13 |      10 | 2023-01-17 17:37:33.865408
 239 | files  | Post        |       151 |     227 | 2023-02-03 17:16:23.648618
 240 | files  | Post        |       151 |     226 | 2023-02-03 17:16:23.666388
```

```
connect_development=# SELECT * FROM active_storage_attachments;
 id  |  name  | record_type | record_id | blob_id |         created_at         
-----+--------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------------------------
  10 | avatar | User        |        13 |      10 | 2023-01-17 17:37:33.865408
 241 | files  | Post        |       151 |     226 | 2023-02-04 00:28:39.485536
 242 | files  | Post        |       151 |     227 | 2023-02-04 00:28:39.519174
```

In development, after saving the post after re-ordering the image, the re-order persists. In production, the re-order doesn't persist after refreshing the page.

Would anyone have ideas why this would be?

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: Just checking: can you call that @post.files.attach method successfully in isolation from this code (in production)?

Comment: Yes! Before implementing the re-order feature, the line ```files_params.pluck('signed_id').each { |i| @post.files.attach(i) } if files_params``` worked to attach the files in production. It still seems to be working as the files are still getting attached properly. 

I added ```@post.files.detach if files_params``` for the re-order feature. This doesn't seem to be working as the files are not being re-ordered.